# How to get the MonoGame Templates working with Visual Studio C# 2013 Express?

Tags: monogame

I've been looking around forever, and I can't seem to find a way to install the MonoGame C# Templates for Visual Studio 2013 Express. These include things like "SpriteFont", etc. that pop up in the templates menu when you click "Add New Item" in the solution menu. I've installed every last MonoGame related thing I can find on the internet and NOTHING has solved my problem.

To clarify, I have all the *project* templates that come with MonoGame:
[image]

but I'm missing all the item templates:
[image]

There should be templates in the list there labelled "SpriteFont" and other miscellaneous MonoGame related templates.

So how do I get the MonoGame templates?

**EDIT:** For the record, I have already tried following the advice given [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90006/adding-spritefont-in-monogame?rq=1), [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46128/how-to-generate-spritefonts-for-monogame/48575), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwtQn02oy6A), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714150/cannot-find-spritefont-template-using-monogame-in-visual-studio-2012-express-wi) [and here](http://stackoverflow.com.80bola.com/questions/26767332/cannot-create-spritefont-visual-studio-2013). I also learnt from the 5th link that apparently I don't have the MonoGame template projects for things like "Empty Content Project" either.

**EDIT 2:** [This](https://dementedvice.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/let-me-explain-install-xna-on-visual-studio-2013-and-2012/) didn't work either.

**EDIT 3:** I've also followed the advice [here](http://community.monogame.net/t/mono-game-on-vs-2013-express/689), yet again to no avail (what a surprise!).

Comment: Did you run the installer here http://www.monogame.net/2015/03/16/monogame-3-3-2/?

Comment: Yes I have ran that installer (the first one).

Comment: Monogame content project is there if you scroll up. http://i.gyazo.com/ae93ac2fa4aa0d74ac442d0b19ee207a.png

Comment: Not for me. You have a folder labelled "XNA Game Studio 4.0" on the side there, whereas I don't, despite the fact that I've installed it and copied over the files from Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 (as is done in the third link).

Comment: there is no need to do that, we can chat if you want http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22587/chat-for-monogame-templates

Comment: @Shiro you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Problem is I don't have the actual link of the file I sent you. If you have it post it and accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the templates for the Monogame content project. You have to install the [XNA game studio 4.0](https://github.com/iliyalesani/XNA-Game-Studio) because Monogame content pipeline uses the XNA pipeline under the hood.

The file `XNA Game Studio 4.0.vsix` is the template installer for visual studio 2013.